# Mqtt Client in Vue.js (Change Vue.use parameters)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mqtt

I'm developing a vue.js Application. One of my pages needs to have the opportunity to connect to a mqtt broker und subscribe to a topic.
Maybe this problem is easy to handle for more experienced users. 
I tried it with the **vue-mqtt** package. I need to import the plugin by usins "Vue.use" at beginning of creating the app in the main.js. It is afaik a one time integration because its in the Vue instance.
Inside of Vue.use i hand over the broker url as parameter.
Is there a way to change it afterwards from inside a component?

I also tried the mqtt.js and paho integration but got errors in chrome. Firefox worked with the test.mosquito.org broker, but not with my own broker at localhost. If there is no workaround for my first issue in this thread,im going to give more information about the paho errors.

thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't a single technical question here. Edit the question to be a single question, e.g. show the code you used from either MQTT.js or Paho JS client and include the errors. Please read the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what a good question needs. SO posts are a single question, not a "thread" for on going discussion.

Answer (score -1):

This is a code sample for MQTT WebSocket in Element + Vue.js

[EMQ X Dashboard MQTT-WebSocket](https://github.com/emqx/emqx-dashboard-frontend/blob/master/src/views/WebSocket.vue#L344)

Comment: This is basically a link only answer which becomes useless as soon as the link breaks. Answers should contain the substance and links should only be for reference.